# jQuery - find the most inner element of the container element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How do I access the most inner element of the given one?
eg.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <p>
                <div>
                    <i>
                    </i>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there some kind of selector allowing you to get directly to the  element starting from the container `<div>` ?? Plese consider `<i>` might not be known, it could be something else

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, just has similar code. This asks for leaf nodes of a specific element with no known tag names.

Comment: @mdenton8, yup, and the accepted answer is applicable if you remove the element part of the selector.

Comment: not a duplicate, it will give the same result for the sample html, but in general it is different

Comment: Sorry, Mr. Hamidi, he is asking for the most efficient way to get leaf nodes WITHIN A CONTAINER. Therefore it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I suppose there is no CSS selector for this. You need a JS code for it...

Comment: Yes Mr. Bako appears to be right.

Comment: If your markup was valid (ie. you didn't have a `div` within a `p`) you'd be able to use: `$('.container').find('*:last')` to get the deepest descendent

Comment: `:last` is not the deepest, if he has another `div` in `.container`, then that will be the last

Comment: @BalintBako given the code in the question it would be, though I take your point about adding another `div`

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = $('.container');

while(element.children().length != 0) {
    element =element.children();
}
```

Comment: You should elaborate a bit about **why** and **how** it works, not just give the code.

Comment: `children` just like the W3C DOM equivalent will access all children elements, including single-tag entities. So this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Check this jQuery code:

```
var maxDepth = 0;
$('*').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('depth', $(this).parents().length);
    if ($(this).parents().length > maxDepth)
        maxDepth = $(this).parents().length;
});

$('[depth="' + maxDepth + '"]').css('background','black');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5SQM/)

It might be far from optimal, but it gets the job done.

Version 2, without modifying the DOM:

```
var maxDepth = 0;
var deepestElements = [];
$('*').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('depth', $(this).parents().length);
    if ($(this).parents().length == maxDepth){
        deepestElements.push($(this));
    } else if ($(this).parents().length > maxDepth){
        deepestElements = [];
        deepestElements.push($(this));
        maxDepth = $(this).parents().length;
    }

});
$(deepestElements).each(function(){
    $(this).css('background','black');
});
```

[jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/B5SQM/1/)

Comment: I would suggest deleting .attr() and using .data() so that you are not adding non-standard attributes, like 'depth', to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is a more visual solution as you can see the depth on the DOM, which was my initial goal

Comment: Also, my code is working now and provides much less confusion and overhead. It also doesn't use the slow * selector. I believe Marginean Vlad's code uses a similar method as mine.

Comment: Good point. You wrote good code, it's a perfectly respectable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way:

```
function innerMost( root ) {
    var $children = $( root ).children();

    while ( true ) {
        var $temp = $children.children();
        if($temp.length > 0) $children = $temp;
        else return $children;
    }
}

var $inner = innerMost($('.container'));
```

My original solution that works with your markup, but not any:

```
$('.container').find(':not(:has(*))');
```

Comment: This is returning every element without a child element

Comment: Is that not exactly what he asked for? Consider undoing your downvote.

Comment: no, that is not what he asked for. Check this: `<div class="container">
        <div>
            <p>
                <div>
                    <i>
                    </i>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
  <div>
  </div>
    </div>` I agree that it does the same for the sample, but it is not an answer to this problem in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var maxDepth = 0, el;

var $ct = $('.container');
var els = $ct.find(':not(:has(*))');
els.each(function(){
    var depth = $(this).parentsUntil($ct).length;
    if(depth > maxDepth){
        maxDepth = depth;
        el = this;
    }
})

$(el).html('as')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xAsvz/)